# matplotlib plot csv file of all columns

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a csv file which contains 20 columns. Right now I can plot using this code taking first column as x axis and rest of them as y axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.genfromtxt('cs.csv',delimiter=',', dtype = float)

a = [row[0] for row in data]
b = [row[1] for row in data]
c = [row[2] for row in data]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg = 'w')
ax.plot(a,b,'g',lw=1.3)
ax.plot(a,c,'r',lw=1.3)
plt.show()
```

The problem is here I have to define all the columns by using

> a = [row[0] for row in data]

this code for all columns one by one. What I want actually to have some method so that it can plot all 19 columns taking first column as x axis constant and plot them in a single window. Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
[plt.plot(data[0],data[x]) for x in range(1,len(data[:,0]))]
```

Comment: hi, could you pls tell what is a stands for in range(1,len(a[:,0]))]

Comment: Hi, typo on my part. It should have been `data`. Now updated.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which uses matplotlib for plotting. For example, if you have a CSV like this:

```
a,b,c
20,2,5
40,6,8
60,4,9
```

You can plot columns `b` & `c` like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=False)
df.b.plot(color='g',lw=1.3)
df.c.plot(color='r',lw=1.3)
```

The first column, is used as the index & x-axis by default.
See the [plotting documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-with-matplotlib) for more details.

Comment: i am having a problem with panda. AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'. is it due to the installation or different version. any idea please.

Comment: `DataFrame` has always been part of pandas as far as I am aware. Did you install it with pip?

Answer (score 0):

As Matti John said, Pandas is the way forward and you can do what you asked even easier. Assuming your CSV is a similar form to the one he posted, you can plot all columns (except the first) against the first column like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('name_of_file.csv', index_col=0)
df.plot(x=df.index, y=df.columns)
```

Using the CSV that Matti John gave, Namely

```
a,b,c
20,2,5
40,6,8
60,4,9
```

This is the output from the code above
[image]