# New to Python, how can I loop this?

Tags: python

[Example of what I need to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D12en.png) I have attached the code below, currently it is limited to manually entering s.x (where x is a-z), is there any way I can use a for loop so that it just plots all the values in the csv file?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.read_csv('test.csv') #reads the .csv file
xmin = 750 #change as needed with your application
xmax = 2800 #change as needed with your application

plt.plot(s.energy, s.a, s.energy, s.b, s.energy, s.c, s.energy, s.d, s.energy, s.e, s.energy, s.f)

axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
plt.xlabel('Energy (eV)')
plt.ylabel('Intensity (counts/nC)')
plt.title('Test')
plt.savefig("test.png", dpi = 600)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop, Pandas has already read the whole file and can plot whole columns. You just need to get the correct parameters in your call to `plot`. Would be useful to include a sample of your data and the plot you are hoping to generate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib plot csv file of all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084851/matplotlib-plot-csv-file-of-all-columns)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but you can plot multiple lines in a loop like this:

```
for y in [s.a, s.b, s.c]:
    plt.plot(s.energy, y)
```

If you have an unknown number of columns, I'd try (mockup code, idk the syntax):

```
i = 0
while columns[i] is not empty:
    plt.plot(x, y)
    i += 1
```

Comment: So i have a csv file with many columns, the first is "energy" which is the x axis, then anywhere from 5-14 columns for intensity which is the y axis. All of these columns use the same x axis, i'm trying to find a way to be able to just give it a csv file, and have it plot no matter how many columns there are.

Comment: @RaivatSinghania is there a way to check if a column is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, loop to all columns

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.read_csv('test.csv') #reads the .csv file
xmin = 750 #change as needed with your application
xmax = 2800 #change as needed with your application

for i in s.columns:

   plt.plot(s[i])

   axes = plt.gca(projection='polar')
   axes.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
   plt.xlabel('Energy (eV)')
   plt.ylabel('Intensity (counts/nC)')
   plt.title('Test')
   plt.savefig("test.png", dpi = 600)
   plt.legend()
   plt.show()
```

Comment: this gave me a blank plot @benai

Comment: You probably shouldn't save the figure before adding the legend, and you might not want to put it all in the for loop

Comment: @Raivat Singhania i have updated the code can you check